# show/hide TOC at the beginning of each section

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

Thanks to the reply (of samcarter) that I received [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368396/hide-show-subsections-in-beamer-presentation) I can show at the beginning of each section the table of contents highlighting the current section and the subsections of it.

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\title{Beamer Class Usetheme Antibes}  
\author{Sascha Frank} 
\date{\today} 

\AtBeginSection{%
\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection, subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]
\end{frame}
}


\begin{document}
%\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.14]{logo-SF}}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame} 


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of contents}
\tableofcontents[hidesubsections]
\end{frame} 


\section{Section no.1} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frame title} 
Each frame should have a title.
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection no.1.1  }
\begin{frame}
Without title somethink is missing. 
\end{frame}


\section{Section no. 2} 
\subsection{Lists I}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{unnumbered lists}
\begin{itemize}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX{}  
\item Course 2 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX{}  
\item Beamer class
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{lists with single pauses}
\begin{itemize}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX{}  \pause 
\item Course 2 \pause 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX{}  \pause 
\item Beamer class
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{lists with pause}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX{}  
\item Course 2
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX{}  
\item Beamer class
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame}



\subsection{Lists II}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{numbered lists}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX{}   
\item Course 2 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX{}  
\item Beamer class
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{numbered lists with single pauses}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX{}  \pause 
\item Course 2 \pause 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX{}  \pause 
\item Beamer class
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{numbered lists with pause}
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX{}  
\item Course 2
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX{}  
\item Beamer class
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I want to add now another section at the end of this MWE but this time the TOC will not appear at the beginning of this section.

```
\section*{Remerciements}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{JE VOUS REMERCIE DE VOTRE ATTENTION.}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
```

creates a section that does not appear to the TOC but nevertheless the TOC appears at the beginning of this section with the rest of the sections unhighlighted. I want to avoid this extra frame.

Comment: Side-note: It would be a slightly better practice (i.e. semantically more correct) to use `\begin{block}{\MakeUppercase{Je vous remercie de votre attention.}}` instead of using full caps in your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a Boolean variable which toggles the additional toc-frame:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\title{Beamer Class Usetheme Antibes}  
\author{Sascha Frank} 
\date{\today} 

\newif\ifshowtoc
\showtoctrue% toggles to show the toc

\AtBeginSection{%
\ifshowtoc
\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection, subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]
\end{frame}
\fi
}


\begin{document}
%\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.14]{logo-SF}}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame} 


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of contents}
\tableofcontents[hidesubsections]
\end{frame} 


\section{Section no.1} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frame title} 
Each frame should have a title.
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection no.1.1  }
\begin{frame}
Without title somethink is missing. 
\end{frame}


\section{Section no. 2} 
\subsection{Lists I}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{unnumbered lists}
\begin{itemize}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX{}  
\item Course 2 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX{}  
\item Beamer class
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{lists with single pauses}
\begin{itemize}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX{}  \pause 
\item Course 2 \pause 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX{}  \pause 
\item Beamer class
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{lists with pause}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX{}  
\item Course 2
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX{}  
\item Beamer class
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame}



\subsection{Lists II}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{numbered lists}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX{}   
\item Course 2 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX{}  
\item Beamer class
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{numbered lists with single pauses}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX{}  \pause 
\item Course 2 \pause 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX{}  \pause 
\item Beamer class
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{numbered lists with pause}
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX{}  
\item Course 2
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX{}  
\item Beamer class
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\showtocfalse% toggles to not show the toc
\section*{Remerciements}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{JE VOUS REMERCIE DE VOTRE ATTENTION.}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works as desired. I learnt a lot of 
new things today:-)!

Answer (score 3):

`\AtBeginSection` has the option to specify the behaviour for starred sections separately:

```
\AtBeginSection[<starred section>]{<normal section>}
```

So if you want to do nothing for the starred section, you could use:

```
\AtBeginSection[]{%
\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection, subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]
\end{frame}
}
```